# Purpose of this type-c port

Tags: laptop, usb-3.1-type-c

What is the purpose of this type-c port, the left-most port I am using to connect my laptop charger. I wanted to connect a type-c to HDMI connector to this but it is not working. The laptop I am using is **LENOVO_MT_20X1_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad L14 Gen 2** any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: It’s a Thunderbolt connector with a proprietary extension connector for Lenovo docks. // Please provide details about the USB-C to HDMI adapter you are trying to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Lenovo website](https://www.lenovo.com/de/de/p/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpadt/t14-g2-(intel)/22tpt14t4n2#ports_slots) this is a USB-C Thunderbolt™ 3 connector.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It looks like it is a Type C USB with power always on (for charging a device from it's battery when the Laptop is turned off).  The Lenovo should have it's own HDMI port and will not necessarily support another via USB.

Comment: There is no need to guess. The Thunderbolt symbol is for Thunderbolt. It’s not about Always-on USB power.